# How to fix the "jump" that happens with the remaining elements in a navbar when I hide elements on the navbar?

Tags: jquery, css, bootstrap-4, hide, element

I'm trying to solve a little jump problem with my h5 elements in my navbar, I'm using bootstrap4 and jQuery.

What happens is that in my navbar I have an icon, a "h5" and a "p" elements on top of each other in that order, 4 of those one beside the other, and when scrolled down the page I want to keep only the "h5".

I managed that with js hide and show methods, but when they finish hiding and the display is set to "none" my "h5" jumps a little to occupy the center of the navbar.

I wanted a solution for that little jump at the end.

I've already tried transitions with opacity, visibility, height = 0 e so on..they kind of work but then I need to adjust the h5 position again manually and I wanted to know if is there a simpler solution for this.

```
<!--NAVBAR-->
<nav id="mainNavbar" class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark fixed-top" >  
  <a class="navbar-brand px-5" href="#home"><i class="fas fa-spa"></i></a>
  <ul class="navbar-nav  w-100 justify-content-around">
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#home">
      <figure><i class="fas fa-fire-alt"></i><figcaption><h5>Home</h5><p>Informacoes gerais</p></figcaption></figure></a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#info">
      <figure><i class="fab fa-envira"></i><figcaption><h5>Info</h5><p>Informacoes gerais</p></figcaption></figure></a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#servicos">
      <figure><i class="far fa-compass"></i><figcaption><h5>Servicos</h5><p>Informacoes gerais</p></figcaption></figure></a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#contato">
      <figure><i class="far fa-envelope"></i><figcaption><h5>Contato</h5><p>Informacoes gerais</p></figcaption></figure></a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#ajuda"> 
      <figure><i class="fas fa-child"></i><figcaption><h5>Ajuda</h5><p>Informacoes gerais</p></figcaption></figure></a></li>           
  </ul>
</nav>
<!--NAVBAR-->

<div class="container">Lorem1000</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">

  $.noConflict();

$(document).ready(function($){

  $(document).scroll(function(){
    if ($(document).scrollTop() > $("#mainNavbar").height()) {
        $("figure i").hide(500);
        $("figure p").hide(500);
        $("nav").css("height", "50px");
     }
    else {
        $("figure i").show(500);
        $("figure p").show(500);
        $("nav").css("height", "128px");
    };
 }); 
});
</script>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    position: relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: rgb(65, 61, 61);
}

nav {
    background-color: dimgray;

}

#mainNavbar {
     padding-bottom: 0;
     transition: all 0.7s ease;
}


.navbar-brand {
    color:white;

}

.navbar-brand .active {
    color: red;
}

.navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link{
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100px;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    transition: all 0.8s ease;
}

.navbar-nav .nav-item .active {
      color: rgb(223, 5, 5) !important;

 }

}
```

What I wanted was to simply make the icon and the "p" going away smoothly when the user scrolls down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are in the right direction. It all depends on what "smoothly" means to your project.

The more simple and easy solution is to remove the transition time from the `hide` and `show` functions, like this:

```
if ($(document).scrollTop() > $("#mainNavbar").height()) {
    $("figure i").hide();
    $("figure p").hide();
    $("nav").css("height", "50px");
 }
else {
    $("figure i").show();
    $("figure p").show();
    $("nav").css("height", "128px");
};
```

I would also suggest changing the transition time of the `#mainNavbar` to **0.4s** instead of **0.8s**

The reason is:

HTML Elements will take a space of the screen unless they have a `display: none` or a `position: absolute or fixed` property. That means that the space they are using, will not be "available" until they are completely gone. That's why your `<h5>` will "jump" only after the time to hide the element is over. Changing that time to 0 (or simply removing it) will make the "jump" "invisible" for the user because you removed that delay.

About the `#mainNavbar` transition from **0.8s** to **0.4s**, that's just to help with the fact that you immediately hide the image and the `<p>`.

Again, this will depend on how "smoothly" you need your project to be, but I think with that configuration you have a good visual effect following the standard of other websites.

If you need the image and the `<p>` to disappear slowly, then you will need to manually change the position of your `<h5>` (as you already know). You could either include a `transition` property to the `<h5>` CSS or use a `timeOut` to move your `<h5>` after the image and the `<p>` are gone.

---

### UPDATE

If you need to slowly hide the icons and `<p>`, the best solution is probably to set everything with `position: fixed`, so nothing will take each other's space.

In summary, your `<a>` or `.nav-link` would need a `position: relative` and all the children (icon, `<h5>` and `<p>`) would have a `position: fixed`. You could then use the javascript function you already have to change the `<h5>` `top` attribute.

Please note that you would need to realign things, find the right `top` and `left` attributes, now that position changed :(

Here is a working example:
https://codepen.io/brunomont/pen/XQoZrL

Comment: Thanks Bruno for you anwser, it helped me a lot! Now one thing that I noticed was that in your codepen in the "p" element, a part of the text just dissapears immediately and dosen't fade out, do you know why that happens ?

Comment: Yep I did that as well and it helped. And you know if with those fixed positions I'll have to adjust them separately when comes to mobile resolutions ?

Comment: Just saw that as well. It is because of the space...I added a `width` and `height` and make it really slow so you can see what is happening. The codepen is updated.

Comment: Yes, you will need to add some media queries for mobile to do a little adjust. That's another reason I would recommend going with the first option of making things faster :)

Comment: That's it then great, Bruno, ended up going with the first solution :)